# How to ensure finalize() is always called (Thinking in Java exercise)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalize

I'm slowly working through Bruce Eckel's *Thinking in Java 4th edition*, and the following problem has me stumped:

> Create a class with a finalize( ) method that prints a message. In main( ), create an object of your class. Modify the previous exercise so that your finalize( ) will always be called.

This is what I have coded:

```
public class Horse {
    boolean inStable;
    Horse(boolean in){
        inStable = in;
    }   
    public void finalize(){
        if (!inStable) System.out.print("Error: A horse is out of its stable!");
    }
}
public class MainWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Horse h = new Horse(false);
        h = new Horse(true);
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

It creates a new `Horse` object with the boolean `inStable` set to `false`. Now, in the `finalize()` method, it checks to see if `inStable` is `false`. If it is, it prints a message.

Unfortunately, no message is printed. Since the condition evaluates to `true`, my guess is that `finalize()` is not being called in the first place. I have run the program numerous times, and have seen the error message print only a couple of times. I was under the impression that when `System.gc()` is called, the garbage collector will collect any objects that aren't referenced.

Googling a correct answer gave me [this link](http://greggordon.org/java/tij4/initialization/BankTest.java), which gives much more detailed, complicated code. It uses methods I haven't seen before, such as `System.runFinalization()`, `Runtime.getRuntime()`, and `System.runFinalizersOnExit()`.

Is anybody able to give me a better understanding of how `finalize()` works and how to force it to run, or walk me through what is being done in the solution code?

Comment: "I was under the impression that when System.gc() is called, the garbage collector will collect any objects that aren't referenced" In your case, there *is* in fact a reference to your object, so why should it be destroyed? Also, I don't think it's guaranteed that `System.gc()` actually recycles anything.

Comment: On the line

`h = new Horse(true);`

I set **h** to a new object, making the previous one (which had **inStable** set to false) unreferenced.

Comment: Yeah, in that case consult the second half of my comment. There are no guarantees. The solution from that external page is actually not a real solution

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When the garbage collector finds an object that is eligible for collection but has a `finalizer` it does not deallocate it immediately. The garbage collector tries to complete as quickly as possible, so it just adds the object to a list of objects with pending finalizers. The finalizer is called later on a separate thread.

You can tell the system to try to run pending finalizers immediately by calling the method [`System.runFinalization`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#runFinalization()) after a garbage collection.

But if you want to *force* the finalizer to run, you have to call it yourself. The garbage collector does not *guarantee* that any objects will be collected or that the finalizers will be called. It only makes a "best effort". However it is rare that you would ever need to force a finalizer to run in real code.

Comment: I think I understand now. I consulted the official solutions guide, which used

`System.gc(); 
    System.runFinalization();`
This works when I try it. I assume that **System.gc()** needs to be called before **System.runFinalization()**, because it essentially "marks" the object as "to-finalize", so that when I run System.runFinalization(), it has an object to actually run. Is this the case, or am I inaccurate in my observations?

Comment: @MattDs17: That might be the way your specific JVM is implemented, but it's not specified to work this way.

Comment: @MattDs17: When the garbage collector runs, it sees that the object is not live and notes that the object needs finalizing. The finalizer is not run yet though. There are no guarantees about precisely when it runs, but calling `System.runFinalization();` makes it *likely* to be run.

Comment: I think I understand now: it's basically a suggestion to do it, but no guarantee. Like Mark said, there is rarely the need to force finalization in real code, so I'm not going to lose sleep over it... thank you guys for the help!

Comment: This is, of course, part of the reason you should [avoid finalizers in the first place](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=effective+java+avoid+finalizers&source=bl&ots=yYGkMgn-QZ&sig=o66EY94GVzB3uvNOvj9eLhdI35k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0nsxUPeHHILp0gHx1oBI&ved=0CGMQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20avoid%20finalizers&f=false).

Comment: Broken link on "System.runFinalization"

Comment: @Elenasys: Thanks, fixed the link to point at the newest documentation.

Comment: "However it is rare that you would ever need to force a finalizer to run in real code."  That's only because the lack of a guarantee means that finalizers are essentially worthless for anything critical, like writing data or releasing system locks.  If finalizers actually worked, there would be tons of usages for them.

Comment: @TomSwirly `C# enters the chat`: How may I help you Tom?

Answer (score 1):

Outside of toy scenarios, it's generally not possible to ensure that a `finalize` will always be called on objects to which no "meaningful" references exist, because the garbage collector has no way of knowing which references are "meaningful".  For example, an `ArrayList`-like object might have a "clear" method which sets its count to zero, and makes all elements within the backing array eligible to be overwritten by future `Add` calls, but doesn't actually clear the elements in that backing array.  If the object has an array of size 50, and its `Count` is 23, then there may be no execution path by which code could ever examine the references stored in the last 27 slots of the array, but there would be no way for the garbage-collector to know that.  Consequently, the garbage-collector would never call `finalize` on objects in those slots unless or until the container overwrote those array slots, the container abandoned the array (perhaps in favor of a smaller one), or all rooted references to the container itself were destroyed or otherwise ceased to exist.

There are various means to encourage the system to call `finalize` on any objects for which no strong rooted references happen to exist (which seems to be the point of the question, and which other answers have already covered), but I think it's important to note the distinction between the set of objects to which strong rooted references exist, and the set of objects that code may be interested in.  The two sets largely overlap, but each set can contain objects not in the other.  Objects' finalizers` run when the GC determines that the objects would no longer exist but for the existence of finalizers; that may or may not coincide with the time code they cease being of interest to anyone.  While it would be helpful if one could cause finalizers to run on all objects that have ceased to be of interest, that is in general not possible.

Answer (score 0):

A call to garabage collecter (`System.gc()`) method **suggests** that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse (i.e its just a suggestion to the jvm, and does not bind it to perform the action then and there, it may or may not do the same). When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects. finalize() is called by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (partially, but it does illustrate the idea):

```
class OLoad {

    public void finalize() {
        System.out.println("I'm melting!");
    }
}

public class TempClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OLoad();
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

The line **new OLoad();** does the trick, as it creates an object with no reference attached. This helps **System.gc()** run the finalize() method as it detects an object with no reference. Saying something like **OLoad o1 = new OLoad();** will not work as it will create a reference that lives until the end of main(). Unfortunately, this works *most of the time*. As others pointed out, there's no way to ensure **finalize()** will be always called, except to call it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

run new constructor() and System.gc() more than twice.

```
public class Horse {
    boolean inStable;
    Horse(boolean in){
        inStable = in;
    }   
    public void finalize(){
        if (!inStable) System.out.print("Error: A horse is out of its stable!");
    }
}
public class MainWindow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
            Horse h = new Horse(false);
            h = new Horse(true);
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```